# Twitter api. Отслеживание действий юзера

Tags: php, api, twitter, twitter-api

Изучаю api твиттера и столкнулся с одной сложной задачей. Нужно отследить, сделал ли пользователь ретвит, либо лайк, либо прокомментировал твит. Придумал костыль, который очень долго обрабатывает мои запросы. Но я думаю, что есть у api этот функционал, благодаря которому можно отслеживать, сделал ли юзер ретвит или другие любые действия. Подскажите, может, знает кто?

Написал модель, в которой генерирую ссылку. В этой же функции проверяю есть ли у юзера такой твит. Такой себе способ, на самом деле. Что посоветуете?

```
/**
 * @param $url
 * @return string
 */
public static function generateUrl($url)
{
    $user = TwitterCheck::getUser();
    $myUsername = substr($user->twitter_profile_link, 20);
    $username = TwitterCheck::getTwitterUsername($url);

    $timeline = TwitterCheck::getTwitterTimeline($username);
    $timelineUser = TwitterCheck::getTwitterTimeline($myUsername);

    foreach ($timeline as $item){
        foreach ($timelineUser as $userItem){
            $createdAt = substr($item['created_at'],0,11);
            $today = substr(date("D M d Y"),0,11);
            if ($createdAt == $today && $userItem['text'] != $item['text']){
                $urlId = $item['id'];
            }
        }

    }
    return 'https://twitter.com/intent/retweet?tweet_id='.$urlId;
}
```

Comment: Покажите, какой вы там костыль сделали.

Comment: Прикрепил код выше